# Putting a code behind a button in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to add a code behind the add button my code is this:

```
class CalculateValues
    {
        private int _num1;
        private int _num2;


        public int Num1
        {
            get
            {
                return _num1;
            }
            set
            {
                _num1 = value;
            }
        }
        public int Num2
        {
            get
            {
                return _num2;
            }
            set
            {
                _num2 = value;
            }
        }
        public virtual int calculate()
        {
            return _num1 + _num2;

        }
    }
```

Here is the other code that has the button on it:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            CalculateValues myAdd = new CalculateValues();
            MulitplyValues Add = new MulitplyValues();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int total = myadd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));    
            MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());

        }
```

But everytime it tell me   `'myAdd' does not exist in the current context`
I am not understanding why it is not working. I have even tried a few different ways.

Comment: in the `button1_Click` method, it should be `myAdd`, not `myadd`. Names are case-sensitive in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a scope issue. You define `myAdd` inside the constructor `Form2()`, which means it'll only be available in that *scope*: only the constructor can use it, after that it's gone.

If you want a variable to persist, move it to the class scope.

I recommend reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Move `myAdd` to the class scope. in your code, `myAdd` "lives" only in the ctor scope.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    CalculateValues myAdd; < ====
    MulitplyValues Add;    < ====
    public Form2()
    {   
        myAdd = new CalculateValues();   < ====             
        Add = new MulitplyValues();      < ====
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int total = myadd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));    
        MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());

    }
}
```

**It's the same issue with `Add`**

Comment: Yes I seen that.. It either the myAdd or Add it gives me the same problem.

Comment: @taylor1984. Is it "cool" now? BTW you need to change from `myadd` to `myAdd` C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yess I did that too and then I get another error saying Error1'WindowsFormsApplication2.CalculateValues' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication2.CalculateValues' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @taylor1984. Well. Does the `CalculateValues` has an `Add` method?

Comment: Well I guess from looking at the code up there no it dont I have a get and set.

Answer (score 1):

`myAdd` is locally scoped to the `Form2` constructor. Declare it for the class instead:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    CalculateValues myAdd;
    public Form2()
    {
        myAdd = new CalculateValues();
        MulitplyValues Add = new MulitplyValues();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to do also something like this:

```
 public Form2()
{
       CalculateValues myAdd = new CalculateValues();
       MulitplyValues Add = new MulitplyValues();
       InitializeComponent();
       button.Click += (o,e)=> {
              int total = myadd.Add(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));    
              MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
       }
}
```

Check if this is work for you.

Comment: WindowsFormsApplication2.CalculateValues' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication2.CalculateValues' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @taylor1984: don't understand. But how do you use it inside your code now ? Has `CalculateValues` that function or not?

Comment: I have tried the  CalculateValues just like you got it and uptop the public forms.